# Combine SSRS Table Rows

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Really simple question. Not used SSRS in a while so struggling.

I have a Data Set which looks something like this:
Employee ID, FirstName, Surname, PhoneType, PhoneNumber

Which returns something like:
MBY, Mark, Berry, M, 0771234566
MBY, Mark, Berry, H, 01757123455

I create a table to display the information. I create 2 calculated fields, one to display Mobile, one to display Home number (using an expression =IIf(Fields!Code.Value = "M", Fields!Number.Value, "")

The problem I have is the table displays 2 rows for each person, one with mobile number, one with home number.

ID  First   Surname Mobile  Home

MBY Mark    Berry   0771234566 *blank*
MBY Mark    Berry   *blank* 01757123455

I know there must be an easy solution, I’m guessing using groups but I don’t know how! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the dataset returns 2 records for your sample data. If so then...
Use a Matrix. Add a Row Group that groups by EmployeeID and a Column Group that groups by PhoneType. This will give you what you need.

If you need a more complete answer let me know and I'll knock something up.